# BackBone client with a remote Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, cordova, backbone.js, client-server

**Background:**

I use  "rails g scaffold hotel name stars:integer" to start fast (and insert into the database  some records),
and write a Backbone client outside the rails app.

I open the Backbone client locally with Safari file:///Users/lg/Workspace/www/index.html for testing the client because my idea is to put the rails server on a host (ex. Heroku) and insert the Backbone client into a PhoneGap App.

My backbone client is only few lines:

```
Hotel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    console.log("initialize Hotel")
  }

});

Hotels = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Hotel,
  url: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/hotels'
});
```

But when i fetch hotels with backbone, rails responds with the **format.html** and not the **format.json** which Backbone can parse.

**hotels_controller.rb**

```
# GET /hotels
# GET /hotels.json
def index
  @hotels = Hotel.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @hotels }
  end
end
```

**Safari inspector console:**

```
hotels = new Hotels()
Object
hotels.fetch()
Object
hotels.length
0

Request URL:http://0.0.0.0:3000/hotels
Request method:GET
Status code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10

Response Headers
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:2233
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 11 Feb 2012 14:31:52 GMT
Etag:"606da2b7c21ca96c9d71aabccdd439e9"
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09)
```

**EDIT:**
Updated with url set to url: "http://0.0.0.0:3000/hotels.json

it can fatch but can't make others CRUD (example PUT)

```
hotels = new Hotels()
Object

hotels.fetch()
Object

hotels.length
5

hotel = hotels.get(2)
Object

hotel.set({name: "name 2"})
Object

hotel.save()
Object

PUT http://0.0.0.0:3000/hotels.json/2 404 (Not Found)
```

Instead if i set only /hotels it works (but the backbone client must reside on the server)

**EDIT 2:**

uploaded the code on github

https://github.com/RevH/backbonefails

***EDIT 3:***

Another details is if you insert the backboneclient directory into Rails public directory and change 0.0.0.0:3000/hotels.json to /hotels it works fantastic!! But if i separate the client from server and open it with Safari it require .json at the end of the url. this is very strange.

i open a rails issue on github at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5005

Comment: Why don't you just explicitly ask it for json? /hotels.json

Comment: Because Backbone can call all the CRUD methods using REST if i insert only /hotels (and this works, but not with a remote url)

Comment: I don't follow. Surely it can call all the CRUD methods anyway, seeing as they rely on the parameters given and the HTTP method, not the format.

Comment: I update my original post with an example appending at the url the .json format

Comment: The format goes at the end of the URL, not in the middle.

Comment: Why are you loading your website through the file system (`file:///Users/lg/Workspace/www/index.html`) rather than from your development server? (`http://localhost:3000/`)?

Comment: i open through filesystem, as i explained, because i want to create a BackBone client and put it into a PhoneGap App.
however, if i send a application/json request the server must not responds with text/html format when i have a method which handle that request and response with json format

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The important thing to understand is that best practice in Rails is NOT to use the Accept headers.  There is a nice writeup [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2010/11/23/mime-type-resolution-in-rails.html) that explains why in glorious detail. Summary is browser implementation of HTTP Accept headers is broken.  Rails best practice is to set the :format parameter in the request.  However, if you like the accept headers they are supported but the rules around what is a valid accept header in rails can be tricky.  If your accept header matches the following regex:

```
BROWSER_LIKE_ACCEPTS = /,\s*\*\/\*|\*\/\*\s*,/
```

then rails throws it away and defaults to text/html mime type. I know, right? Your header happens to match this.  The reason most people don't have this problem is that rails "fixes" the default jquery behavior in the rails [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js).  They set a ajaxSetup beforeSend callback in JQuery that puts the `*/*` at the beginning of the header, which is what the magic rails regex wants to see though I can't really tell why, other than they know that an unmodified browser request will always put it there.  Here is how you might fix your accept header in JQuery.

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you've set up your rails code so that it requires a call to `/hotels.json` in order to return json, but your backbone code is calling `/hotels` only.

the easiest way to fix this is to have a separate api for json data, than for html pages. for example: `/hotels` returns html and `/api/hotels` return json. see Ryan Bate's Railscasts for an example of this (paid) http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1

another option would be to change your Backbone models / collections so that they append the ".json" to the end of your urls. for example:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function(){
    var url;
    if (this.isNew()){
      url = "/hotels/" + this.id + ".json";
    } else {
      url = "/hotels.json";
    }
    return url;
  }
});
```

There are likely other options as well. These are just two that came up off the top of my head.

Comment: I thought that the call to /hotels with the request headers set to "application/json" was intercepted by Rails automatically with the format.json and not with format.html when i have a methods that responds with format.html AND format.json.

if this is an expected behavior i prefer make a separate api for json
but this doesn't seems very DRY if i have to make a duplicate controller only to handle json in RESTful way.

Comment: Thanks Derick, but if you insert the backboneclient directory into Rails public directory and change http://0.0.0.0:3000/hotels.json to /hotels ***it works fantastic***!! But if i separate the client from server and open it with Safari it require .json at the end of the url. ***this is very strange***.

Comment: another option is to set json as the default in the routes.rb  resources :model_name, defaults: {format: :json}

Answer (score 0):

When your javascript application runs on a different domain, port or protocol than your server, strange things will happen. This is called Same Origin Policy. Just load the javascript from your rails server and everything will be fine.

Comment: Same Origin Policy dosn't apply on file:// protocol

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494770/FAQ

Comment: So then why does it work, when your files are hosted on the rails server?

Comment: i tried on Webbrick local server and Heroku.
i think is a bug of rails because if i have a index method with only `render :json => Hotel.all` (no format.html so) it works fine.
I open a ticket on github also.