# rails json api is returning 406 http error when used from an outside page (backbone and phonegap)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, cordova, backbone.js

I've build a rails 3 application. This application has a json API. I've developed a html+javascript Backbone UI (Jquery ajax) that calls the API. Everything works fine.

Now, I wan't to use this html+js in Phone Gap. When I test the application using chrome, with no security (chromium-browser --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security) I get an 406 error from the API.

I've performed some tests, and the problem is solved when I add ".json" to the url, however, this is not easy to manage inside backbone.

Any one has experienced the same error?

UPDATE
solution found at: [BackBone client with a remote Rails Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241045/backbone-client-with-a-remote-rails-server)

Comment: Solution found at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241045/backbone-client-with-a-remote-rails-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question allready exists, you can find the awnser at:

[BackBone client with a remote Rails Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241045/backbone-client-with-a-remote-rails-server)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should prefix the API routes with something like this

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
  namespace :v1 do
    get "/:param/wat" => "api#wat"
    get "/:username/skills" => "users#skills"
  end
end
```

That `defaults: { format: 'json' }` does the work for you.

Now if you do an http request in /api/v1/jon/skills (for example) you will get Jon's skills in a JSON

Comment: As indicated on comments, repeated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241045/backbone-client-with-a-remote-rails-server